# input type file to folder on submit click angular7

Tags: angular, file, filesystems, angular7

I have a file upload control in my form. I want to save the file after submit click in angular.

In `onfileupload()` method, I am getting filename and size. Now I want to save the file to specific folder in typescript.

If the folder doesn't exists create folder and save. If the folder exists then save.

HTML code:

```html
<input id="avatar" type="file" (change)="File($event)" #file>
<button (click)="Upload()">Upload</button>
```

TYPESCRIPT code:

```ts
selectFile: File;
File(event) {
    this.selectFile= event.target.files[0];
}
```

In typescript page am getting uploaded file name and size.

Comment: I think it's best to install a dependency for file saving functionality. Try to use  `npm install --save file-saver`. For more details, visit this [site](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/16/implementing-file-save-functionality-with-angular-4/).

Answer (score 0):

From Typescript you will be able to save file only in the default download folder of your browser. If you want to save the file in a particular folder, you will have to call a backend service (Java/ASP.NET/Php etc.), pass the file and save it in the desired folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileSaver.js which is an HTML 5 FileSaver functionality.
FileSaver.js is available as a npm package so you can install it as shown below.

```
$npm install --save file-saver
```

And for backend use Rest API so u can use Spring Boot, see the example here:-
https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/16/implementing-file-save-functionality-with-angular-4/

Comment: file saver is directly downloding file, but i have a requirement to save the uploaded file in c drive.

Comment: You have to set the path in your js file to save to c drive